# custom gson convertor in retrofit using GETrequest

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

this is my retrofit interface

```
@GET
void getName(@Query("name") String name, Callback callback);
```

http request for above format is

`/getName?name=abcd`

but in my case url format should go like this

`/getName?name=["abcd"]`

what i want to change in my interface or any gson convertor required to `append [""]` to string. please give with example

Comment: it seems to me like the format required is list of strings instead of just string, I expect that this API is not yours because otherwise you would change it right?

Comment: i tried with list of strings. But it has the same format /getName?name=abcd. i want format look like this /getName?name=["abcd"]

Comment: Please tell how can i do it by gson convertor

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any simple way to do it using Retrofit APIs, but I would just create a method to do it and I would call it on every String I would pass to the adapter

    `public static String enclose(String text) {
        return "[\""+text+"\"]";
    }`

And call it this way

```
    getName(enclose("abcd"), new Callback<String>() {

        @Override
        public void success(String s, Response response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    });
```